# Delete multiple rows by applying the filter (condition) on the column

Tags: mysql, sql

Input:

```
| order_id | status      | order_date |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| ord1     | in_progress | 20221125   | 
| ord1     | in_progress | 20221126   | 
| ord1     | in_progress | 20221127   | 
| ord1     | shipped     | 20221128   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221127   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221128   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221129   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221130   | 
| ord3     | in_progress | 20221126   | 
| ord3     | picked_up   | 20221127   |
```

Expected Output:

```
| order_id | status      | order_date |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221127   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221128   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221129   | 
| ord2     | in_progress | 20221130   |
```

How to delete all the rows of orders from the above example, where the **status** is either **shipped** or **picked_up**?

Comment: There are only 2 rows in your sample data *where the status is either shipped or picked_up*. Can you explain why your expected output contains only 4 rows?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your query. This site is to help you fix problems, not for us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

self join to detect the rows with status you want to delete :

```
delete t1 
from tab t1
join tab t2
on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
and t2.status in ('picked_up', 'shipped');
```